# Gluu Server 2.4.1 not starting on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, federated-identity, identity-management

After install Gluu Server 2.4.1 using the following link:
https://www.gluu.org/docs/admin-guide/deployment/centos7/

when I try to start using command :

```
/sbin/gluu-serverd-2.4.1 start
```

it gives me this error:
Job for systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

then I tried running :

> $ systemctl status systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service -l

and got :

```
● systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service - Container gluu/server/2.4.1
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-02-04 19:04:30 IST; 17min ago
Docs: man:systemd-nspawn(1)
Process: 29808 ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-nspawn --quiet --keep-unit --boot --link-journal=try-guest --network-veth --machine=%I (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 29808 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Status: "Terminating..."

Feb 04 19:04:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Container gluu/server/2.4.1...
Feb 04 19:04:30 localhost.localdomain systemd-nspawn[29808]: Invalid machine name: gluu/server/2.4.1
Feb 04 19:04:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 04 19:04:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Container gluu/server/2.4.1.
Feb 04 19:04:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service entered failed state.
Feb 04 19:04:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd-nspawn@gluu-server-2.4.1.service failed.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for moving this over to the Gluu support site. That's always the best place to get our attention. Progress will be best tracked on your ticket:

https://support.gluu.org/installation/gluu-server-241-not-starting-on-centos-7-2415